# ADFS PowerShell: Scripting Web API (Add-AdfsWebApiApplication) with RuleTemplate in IssuanceTransformRules

Tags: powershell, asp.net-web-api, adfs, adfs4.0

I've defined an ADFS Application Group using the ADFS MMC. I'd like to create a script for deployment.  I've successfully scripted using New-AdfsApplicationGroup and Add-AdfsNativeClientApplication.  Next I'd like to script the Web API.  Looking at the output of Get-AdfsWebApiApplication I see the following IssuanceTransformRules.  The rule is named and references a template.

> @RuleTemplate = "LdapClaims"
>
> @RuleName = "2"
>
> c:[Type ==
>   "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname",
>   Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
>
> => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress",
>   "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", 
>   "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn"), query =
>   ";mail,sAMAccountName,userPrincipalName;{0}", param = c.Value);

I scripted this as:

```
Add-AdfsWebApiApplication -Name "My Web API" -AllowedClientTypes 6 -ApplicationGroupIdentifier "MyApp" -IssueOAuthRefreshTokensTo 2 -TokenLifetime 7 -Identifier {https://apphost/myapp/api/} -IssuanceTransformRules '@RuleTemplate = "LdapClaims", @RuleName = "2", c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"] => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn"), query = ";mail,sAMAccountName,userPrincipalName;{0}", param = c.Value);'
```

This results in the following error.

> Parser error: 'POLICY0030: Syntax error, unexpected COMMA, expecting
>   one of the following: O_SQ_BRACKET IDENTIFIER NOT AT IMPLY .' At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + Add-AdfsWebApiApplication -Name "My Web API" -AllowedClientTypes ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          :InvalidData: (@RuleTemplate =...ram = c.Value);:String) [Add-AdfsWebApiApplication],
>   PolicyValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId: POLICY0002.Microsoft.IdentityServer.Management.Commands.Add-AdfsWebApiApplicationCommand

Removing both @RuleTemplate and @RuleName, the following executes successfully but produces a custom rule that cannot be edited using the graphical template which provides dropdown lists for LDAP Attributes and Outgoing Claim Types.

```
Add-AdfsWebApiApplication -Name "My Web API" -AllowedClientTypes 6 -ApplicationGroupIdentifier "MyApp" -IssueOAuthRefreshTokensTo 2 -TokenLifetime 7 -Identifier {https://apphost/myapp/api/} -IssuanceTransformRules 'c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"] => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn"), query = ";mail,sAMAccountName,userPrincipalName;{0}", param = c.Value);'
```

Might someone suggest a way to include a name or template in the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you include your transform claim data in a variable and then reference variable in your cmdlet?

```
$transformRules = @"
@RuleTemplate = "LdapClaims"

@RuleName = "2"

c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]

=> issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn"), query = ";mail,sAMAccountName,userPrincipalName;{0}", param = c.Value);
"@

Add-AdfsWebApiApplication -Name "My Web API" -AllowedClientTypes 6 -ApplicationGroupIdentifier "MyApp" -IssueOAuthRefreshTokensTo 2 -TokenLifetime 7 -Identifier {https://apphost/myapp/api/} -IssuanceTransformRules $transformRules
```